# chat not found НО ID ЧАТА СУЩЕСТВУЕТ PYTELEGRAMBOTAPI

Tags: python, telegram

```
import telebot
import config


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
chatId = '-853705327'

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def all_messages(message):
    bot.forward_message(chatId, message.chat.id, message.id)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

вот такой вот код...
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found

Answer (score 0):

я не подумал о том, что надо в этот чат самого бота добавить..) добавил - и заработало

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/835705)

Comment: @n1tr0xs является. Другое дело что и вопрос и ответ низкого качества, но тем не менее - в ответе ответ - "добавить самого чатбота в чат" )